# Installing Windows 7 on a dual boot machine

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, grub

My current setup is a dual boot of XP and Ubuntu 9.04. Installed Ubuntu after XP and dual booting with GRUB. I want to install Windows 7 now to make it a triple boot system without disturbing my current settings in XP and Ubuntu.

Need a clean solution please - no file lost and GRUB issues.

I will free up one of my NTFS partition(around 40GB) to install Windows 7, in case this info is needed.

Note : VM is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to restore Grub if [you install Windows 7](http://raviratlami1.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-dual-triple-boot-windows-7-with.html):

> Assuming that you are installing
>   Windows 7 on a separate partition in a
>   machine that had Windows XP and Linux
>   installed already.
>
> If your machine had only Windows XP
>   and no Linux, Windows 7 is generous
>   enough to let you choose to boot older
>   version of Windows through its boot
>   manager.
>
> But, it deliberately ignore other
>   non-windows OS and file system, and
>   hence you can’t boot Linux through
>   Windows 7 boot manager.
>
> In such case, you need to restore GRUB
>   boot manager. Follow these steps
>   carefully and restore your old GRUB:
>
> **Boot through Ubuntu Linux Live CD/DVD**
>
> Start terminal and give following
>   command:
>
> $ sudo grub
>
> You will then enter in grub
>   configuration mode. Here, give
>   following command:
>
> $ root (hd0,0)
>
> Then give following command:
>
> $ setup (hd%1,%2) - here, %1,%2 is the
>   disk volume and partition value of
>   your original Linux installation where
>   /boot/grub is already installed. For
>   example, in my machine, it is on disk
>   1, partition 6, so the value will be –
>   (hd0,5). So, be careful here else your
>   Grub will not be restored, and you
>   will get error message instead.
>
> Finally, give following command within
>   grub configuration mode:
>
> $ quit
>
> $ exit
>
> Now, reboot (do not forget to remove
>   Linux Live CD/DVD to boot from HDD).
>   If everything had gone right, **your
>   Grub boot manager will load and prompt
>   you to choose to boot from either**
>   **Linux or Windows 7**. Enjoy!