# Couldn't dual boot Vista and Centos 5.4

Tags: linux, windows-vista, boot, grub, centos

Today I have installed Centos 5.4 with dual boot with Vista. Everything was fine, but after testing Centos 5.4, when I tried to load Vista, it did not load. After selecting vista from grub menu, it shows the following message:

```
rootnoverify (hd0, 1)
chainloader +1

No bootmgr found
```

I googled and try to fix the boot but failed, Then I restart my machine, boot with vista cd and in rescue option, restore my bootmgr by typing

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

What happened after that, I can load at vista now, but no grub menu shows :P It seems the Centos went totally invisible. I am using dual booting Ubuntu 9.10 and vista in my laptop and its working fine and with no error from the beginning. But installed Centos for one of my project needs and I need it running asap. So I am feeling very helpless. Please help me anyone out there. I know there are many people knows how to fix it. Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you restored the Vista boot manager, you lost Grub. You'll need to recover Grub as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/22952/installing-windows-7-on-a-dual-boot-machine/23108#23108).